# Is it possible to include custom args in an Ember partial?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, partials

There's a piece of code in my template that's repeated multiple times through it... So I want to [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) it.
It's a simple piece of code with no logic on it.

First, I though about creating an array with the title and values for a loop, but then I remembered Handlebars does not allow me to do it.

Second, I though on partials. They're only a part of a template, afterall. But then I noticed it apparently ignores additional arguments. Thus, there's no way to alter it's contents besides what's already in my model. In this and in the prior case, I didn't want to mess my route/controller with template-only variables.

Third, my current solution is a Component, but it seems **so dirty**. However, it's quite troublesome to have a JS file with only an empty object; furthermore, components have no file structure, and I wanted this piece of code to live along with it's original template.

This is a simplification of what I wanted to achieve:

**project/index.hbs**

```
{{partial "counter_block" value=model.count_success title="Yeah!"}}
{{partial "counter_block" value=model.count_failures title="Boo :("}}
```

**project/_counter_block.hbs**

```
<div>
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <span>{{value}}</span>
</div>
```

Is there any solution for this matter or is this just another case where Handlebars oversimplification causes coding issues?

Answer (score 3):

That's when you create a component, the js file isn't necessary, you can just have a template `components/counter-block`

```
{{counter-block value=model.count_success title='Yeah!'}}

{{counter-block value=model.count_failures title='Booo!'}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/suxebehaqe/1/edit

Comment: weird. If I do it Ember complains about not finding a helper with that name - as if the difference between a helper and a component is the lack of the JS file. Going to verify.